# Inserting table into phonegap using jquery

Tags: jquery, cordova

I'm pretty new to coding in general and I am doing a project for online college.
I have a basic phonegap app using myeclise and coding in jquery.
How do you create a table and insert images into the table?
I have copied code from w3schools but it does not seem to work, a blue round loading icon appears when I try enter the page.

```
     <table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td><img src="http://www.bodyenlightenment.me/blog/wp-content/uploads/DoGrainsBreadsandCerealsHaveaPlaceintheN_99C5/iStock_000004292161XSmall.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;"></td>
      <td><img src="http://thegreentribe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/People-Natural-Beauty-Medium.jpeg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;"></td>
      <td><img src="http://media.digitalcameraworld.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/123/2013/08/Summer_portrait_ideas_atmospheric_pictures_people_CAN64.masterclass.finished.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;"></td>
      <td><img src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/designer_2.jpeg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've searched through the forums but have found nothing that truly answers this simple question.  I am running the app on the MyEclipse Mobile Web Simulator.

Comment: Thanks for the information, i got the table working.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no very special need, don't include external sources in a mobile app, there are three reasons:

1. Bad user experience, because of loading.
2. Your app causes traffic, that means for some users that they will have costs.
3. The security problem. It is possible to inject code by external sources.

If you need to include external sources, you have to whitelisten them, follow the docs here:http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html